# How to resolve "not all code paths return a value" on bool method?

Tags: c#, boolean, return, boolean-logic

I've added a `bool` method, that provides performs OAuth authentication and returns a true or false. Bases on the result of the user and password check.

But I'm getting an error on `LoginService()` method, stating that:

```
'MongoDBApp.Services.AuthenticationService.LoginService(string, string)': not all code paths return a value
```

I Googled the error and results show it's becuase as the error says, the method doesn't return the values defined in the method return type.

I've checked the method over and it's returning true or false at each condition.It seems that the bool values aren't being returned outside of the `LoginAsync()` inner method.

Does anyone know why the method is not receiving the bool values returned?

This is the `LoginService()` with return type bool:

```
    private bool LoginService(string username, string password)
    {

        string ConnectionName = "Username-Password-Authentication";

        auth0.LoginAsync(connection: ConnectionName, userName: username, password: password).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Messenger.Default.Send<UpdateLoginMessage>(new UpdateLoginMessage());
                return true;                  
            }

        },

       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Comment: Why just don't you assign value of a bool variable in if-else block, and return it after `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());` ?

Comment: What does TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() return? Long ago, I was taught when writing assembly language it's easier to debug programs that have a common return point. It may not be so necessary now, but I avoid multiple returns at all costs. As a perfectly good answer has pointed out, substitute both return statements with the assignment to a function/method scope return variable. Then return that value at the end of the function/method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `return true` or `return false` in your `LoginService` method, which is what the compiler is complaining about. (You do have `return true` and `return false`, but they're not in `LoginService`, they're in the lambda you're passing to `ContinueWith`, and that lambda is a separate method.)

But even worse, you're starting a `LoginAsync` call to do its work in a background thread, and then returning from your `LoginService` method *immediately,* before that `LoginAsync` -- or the continuation you registered -- have completed. That's almost certainly not what you want.

What you really need is an `async` method:

```
private async Task<bool> LoginServiceAsync(string username, string password)
{
    string ConnectionName = "Username-Password-Authentication";

    try {
        var result = await auth0.LoginAsync(
            connection: ConnectionName, userName: username, password: password);
        Messenger.Default.Send<UpdateLoginMessage>(new UpdateLoginMessage());
        return true;                  
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(It's also a terrible idea to turn exceptions into Boolean results without *at least* logging the exception, but I didn't mess with that part of your logic.)

The caller would then say:

```
var loginResult = await LoginServiceAsync(username, password);
```

At which point all your code would successfully wait for the async calls to complete.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense actually. I'll add in an exception catch on there.